# Access IS NOT NULL appears to be failing

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a table called tbl1. It has a field called: EmailRequestCreateDate. It's date/time information that I've imported as text because date/time failed.

I have written a simple query called qry1 to filter out NULL dates from the table.

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl1
WHERE EmailRequestCreateDate IS NOT NULL;
```

However when I tried to run a cdate conversion on EmailRequestCreateDate it threw an "Invalid use of NULL error."

I shouldn't get be getting NULLS, but when I ran a second query against qry1, it returned a single record.

```
SELECT *
FROM qry1
WHERE EmailRequestCreateDate IS NULL;
```

How is this possible and what can I do to correct it?

Thanks

Comment: What does this one show for `row_count`?  `SELECT Count(*) As row_count FROM qry1 WHERE EmailRequestCreateDate IS NULL;`

Comment: It shows a value of 0

Comment: Since you're using a text field instead of a date field, have you checked for empty string as well?

Comment: @ChrisG That makes sense.  If you're viewing the second query results in Datasheet View, it will show you a "new record" ... which is simply a placeholder for new data but does not mean that record exists in the result set of `qry1`.  Could that be what you're seeing?

Comment: @Taraz this query returns a value of 0 {SELECT Count(*) As row_count
FROM qry1
WHERE EmailRequestCreateDate ="";}

Comment: @HansUp: Entirely possible given that none of the fields are showing values, but why would the cdate throw a null error then? Did I use cdate incorrectly?

Comment: One or more `EmailRequestCreateDate` values contain something which is not Null and which also does not represent a valid date.  What does your `CDate()` query give you if you change `qry1` to this?  `SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE IsDate(EmailRequestCreateDate) = True;`

Comment: `SELECT count(*) as row_count
FROM tbl1
WHERE EmailRequestCreateDate IS NOT NULL;` Returns 822609

Comment: `SELECT Count(*) as row_count
FROM tbl1
WHERE IsDate(EmailRequestCreateDate) = True;` Returns 822609

Comment: Sorry, I'm stumped.  :-(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101217/discussion-between-chrisg-and-hansup).